# Set default syntax highlighting for [azure-sql-database] tag

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

The default syntax highlighting for [azure-sql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database) should be `sql`.

Comment: If it's a sql question, shouldn't it be tagged with sql and sql-server? I think question about specific azure hosting requires other highlightning (e.g: Command Line)

Comment: Questions tagged `azure-sql-database` are typically not also tagged `sql-server` -- this is probably right, since the differences between the engines are minimal enough that if there's nothing Azure-specific about your question, you may as well just tag it `sql-server` only, while if it is specific to hosting, adding `sql-server` isn't helpful. Lots of these questions are not directly SQL related, though, so I do agree the `sql` tag should probably just be added if it is, which will conveniently also take care of the highlighting.

Comment: You don't include the [tag:c#] tag for a question about [tag:task-parallel-library] ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52840506/145173)) that happens to use C# for explanatory code. So would you want to include [tag:sql] for a question that just uses SQL for explanatory code? Unlike .NET frameworks, which work with lots of languages, a SQL database has a natural default language.